# Which collection should be used in this scenario?

Tags: java

Can any one suggest me which collection to use for this scenario:

Every student has a payment history with details of payment made by the student / family. The system should ensure that no duplicate payments are there against a student account. The program should be able to add payment details for a student, and ensure that duplicate payment details are not getting registered.

Comment: I don't think the collection type is going to matter. I think you should perform the duplicate check against the collection yourself rather than relying on the collection to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps a `Map<Student, Set<Payment>>` would do.

(A [`Set`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) won't allow for duplicates.)

If you override `equals` properly (and `hashCode`) you can do something like

```
Map<Student, Set<Payment>> studentPayments =new HashMap<Student, Set<Payment>>();

public void addStudentPayment(Student student, Payment payment) {

    if (!studentPayments.containsKey(student))
        studentPayments.put(student, new HashSet<Payment>());

    if (studentPayments.get(student).add(payment))
        System.out.println("Payment was added");
    else
        System.out.println("Duplicate found. Payment not added.");
}
```

Comment: that requires me to see the rest of your person / payment clasess. Besides, I think you should post a new question for that, giving the details. If you post a link to the question here, I'll have a look at it.

Comment: its just a employment program where there will be savings account and related account for that in the name of a student.And based on his saving every month there will be a credit of 75% in related employment program account.

Comment: I think the best advice I can give you is to have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java) question, and post a more specific follow-up question if that doesn't provide enough info.

Comment: ok Mr aioobe i will try working on that ..if i have anything to clarify i will post ...

Answer (score 3):

whenever you have a requirement for no duplicates, Use a `Set`.  If you use a `HashSet`, make sure to implement `hashCode` on the `Objects` you put in the set (and also `equals`).

Answer (score 1):

You might find a Map of students to a set of payments helpful

```
Map<Student, Set<Payment>> studenthistory;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider e.g.

```
Map<Student, HashSet<Payment>> students;
```

`Student` is the student, identified by name or some ID. `HashSet<Payment>` are the payments. A `Payment` contains an ID, amount, date, etc.

Comment: Surely two payments can be of the same amount. Besides, `Double` is a terrible type for storing currency.

Comment: @aioobe: Agree. Improved now.

Answer (score 0):

A set would be your best choice. A set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements.

Just remember to override the equals-method on your class: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17

In your case, it will be something like:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!obj instanceof Payment)
        return false;
    }
    Payment p = (Payment) o;
    return p.getId().equals(getId());
}
```

.... or something like that :)